# regular expression extract string between two strings

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract strings using regexp.  For example in the following string:

```
select DESCENDANTS([Customer].[Yearly Income],,LEAVES) on axis(0),
       DESCENDANTS([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory],,LEAVES) on axis(1),
       DESCENDANTS([Customer].[Total Children],,LEAVES) on axis(2)
  from [Adventure Works]
 where [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
```

I want to extract the substring between every pair of "DESCENDANTS(" and ",,".

So the result in this case would be: `[Customer].[Yearly Income], [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory], [Customer].[Total Children]`

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you have your text in a string called `query` you can do:

```
query.scan(/DESCENDANTS\((.+),,/).flatten
=> ["[Customer].[Yearly Income]", "[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory]",
"[Customer].[Total Children]"]
```

Some notes:

- `\(` matches the literal open bracket
- `(.+)` remembers the characters between the open bracket and the two commas as a capture
- If the regexp contains captures `()` then `scan` will return an array of arrays of the captured parts for each match. In this case there is only 1 capture per match so `flatten` can be used to return a single array of all the matches we are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

```
/DESCENDANTS\(([^,]+),,/
```

See it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/xLPzJfxPBh)

Comment: that will exclude descendants that happen to contain commas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an uglier variation that uses `split`: split on "DESCENDANTS(" and ",,", and take every other substring:

```
s.split(/DESCENDANTS\(|,,/).each_with_index.inject([]) {|m,(e,i)| m << e if i.odd?; m}
```

Answer (score 0):

.+? is more safe, it works correctly if SQL is in one line.

```
query.scan(/DESCENDANTS\((.+?),,/).flatten
```